# I am using nextjs 13 experimental app with RTK query to make queries SSG,SSR

Tags: next.js, rtk-query, next.js13

if RTK query is wrapper around fetch() and in NextJS13 experimental app is also, will they work together? And How I can change queries so they can revalidate, be SSG or SSR?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

RTK Query author here. Please don't use the `app` directory with RTK Query yet. There is too much going on in there that just doesn't make any sense at the moment to get a good story of even using Redux.
It will hopefully become more clear in the nearer future, but at this point there are no good ways of moving Redux state from server to client in a streaming scenario, or to separate state between different requests meaninfully.

Comment: Is there any new update on this please ?

Comment: You can use it in Client components, where it will run in the browser. Apart from that, no.

Comment: Thank you @phry, i will probably stick to the NextJs Page Router Pattern